# Understanding Firebase promises on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing this question because **I'm retrieving null or data** on different cases. Let me explain it:

**-- GRAPHICAL EXPLANATION --**

I'm developing an app to help animals which can create chats and list the existing ones:

- First, ***when an user create a chat***, (it's going to be *sender*) stores in database the sender and receiver state (sender connected and receiver disconnected) and unread messages number (0 initially)

[image: Chat status]

The chat message which is going to be stored on the lastMessage section (Here, I only store the last message from both users, overriding the last one) and allMessages section (And here, I store all messages from both users)

[image: Chats]

- Second, when the receiver gets the notification of new chat, she/he could access by ***Touching on it or by the chat list***, so Firebase updates the receiver's chatStatus (Connected and 0 unread messages) and the receiver could start to talk.

**-- PROBLEM --**

So, **When the receiver access to the chat with all previous data stored in Firebase** and my app ask if the chat exists (to create it or not, because he/she could be another sender who wants to create another chat) and if the chat status is created, **Firebase is retrieving null**.

I don't know what I did wrong because **chatList can access to the data to list the existing chats by using the lastMessage's sender/receiver** (chats -> lastMessages), but I'm having problems if I need to access to:

- chats -> allMessages
- chatStatus -> animal uid -> home uid -> sender/receiver data

**-- MY ATTEMPT --**

Now, I'm going to show the most important part of **chatList** using addValueEventListener (It's working)

```
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        mUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (mUser != null) {
            // User is signed in
            Log.d("FIREBASE_AUTH", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + mUser.getUid());
        } else {
            // User is signed out
            Log.d("FIREBASE_AUTH", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chatlist);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    setLastChatMessage();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}

private void setLastChatMessage() {
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabaseReference.child("chats").child("lastMessages").child(mUser.getUid())
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot animalsDataSnapshot) {
                    if (animalsDataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                        for (DataSnapshot animalDataSnapshot : animalsDataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            for (DataSnapshot homeSnapshot : animalDataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                              //GETTING THE DATA TO QUERY AGAIN WITH addListenerForSingleValueEvent, LIST THE EXISTING CHATS AND SET INTENTS TO CHAT

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    mDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(this);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.e("databaseError", String.valueOf(databaseError));
                }
            });
}
```

Here, I'm going to show the most important part of **chat** using addListenerForSingleValueEvent and addValueEventListener (It's not working)

```
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {

        mUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if (mUser != null) {
            // User is signed in
            Log.d("FIREBASE_AUTH", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + mUser.getUid());

        } else {
            // User is signed out
            finish();
            Log.d("FIREBASE_AUTH", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarChat);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    // Initialize Firebase Auth
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    setChat();
}

private void setChat() {
    mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabaseReference.child("chats").child("allMessages").child(animalUid).child(homeUid)
            .orderByKey().equalTo("-0valueByDefect")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.getValue() == null) {
                        // IF THERE IS NOT A CHAT, CREATE A NEW ONE
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.e("databaseError", String.valueOf(databaseError));
                }
            });

    mDatabaseReference.child("chatStatus").child(animalUid).child(homeUid)
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                            .child("unreadMessages").getValue() == null) {
                      // IF MY STATUS IS NOT CREATED, ADD IT
                    }
                    mDatabaseReference.removeEventListener(this);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.e("databaseError", String.valueOf(databaseError));
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);
    connectMyUser(true);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    connectMyUser(false);
    if (authListener != null) {
        mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authListener);
    }
}    

private void connectMyUser(boolean isConnected) {
    String myUserUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();

    if (isConnected) {
        childUpdates.put("/chatStatus/" + animalUid + "/" + homeUid
                + "/" + myUserUid + "/state", "connected");
        childUpdates.put("/chatStatus/" + animalUid + "/" + homeUid
                + "/" + myUserUid + "/unreadMessages", 0);
    } else {
        childUpdates.put("/chatStatus/" + animalUid + "/" + homeUid
                + "/" + myUserUid + "/state", "disconnected");
    }

    mDatabaseReference.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}
```

**-- MY APPROACH --**

I have these problems since a week, but yesterday I discovered an *incorrect way* to make it working. On **chatList** I wrote the same queries as Chat, so I'm getting the same result, but when the user access to the chat and the app ask again if that chat exists and if the user have an status, **I'm getting the data**.

I have some questions:

- Do you think if it's an index problem? This is what I have

  {
    "rules": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
      "chatStatus": {
        ".indexOn": ".value"
      },
      "chats": {
        ".indexOn": ".value"
      }
    }
  }
- Maybe I didn't use correctly removeEventListener?
- Should I use addChildEventListener instead of addValueEventListener? I tried it but I had the same result
- Could you explain me what I misunderstood?

---

**-- UPDATE 18/09/2017 --**

Hi, I think I discovered a correct way to solve it: [I used **keepSynced**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-prioritizing-the-local-cache) and as Firebase documentation says:

> The Firebase Realtime Database client automatically downloads the data at these locations and **keeps it in sync even if the reference has no active listeners**.

That's why It's working, but **I still don't understand why I need to use the keepSynced property** because the rest of nodes don't need it (Maybe listeners wasn't active?) and **when I need to change keepSynced to false** if I need firebase listening to that node.

I still wondering if It is an index problem.

**Thanks in advance!!**

Comment: Hi, Are there some firebaser?

Comment: How are you displaying the results?

Comment: Hi @Chisko, what do you mean? when I execute the promise (is it correct saying promise in Android?), I check the datasnapshop and I'm getting null... If I put the keepsynced property, it seems to work, but sometimes not... So I don't know if it's an index problem. Thank you!!

Comment: Hehe no, Promises are a concept related to web and JS. What I mean is how you are trying to display the results you retrieve, because if, for example, you are using a `RecyclerView` you need to setup and correctly attach the adapter to it. Also, are you using the official `FirebaseUI` project as a guide?

Comment: OK, because I don't see where you are returning the initialized adapter and setting it to the recyclerview. Sure you are doing that? Normally you don't have to handle listener changes when you directly use or inherit from a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, you only need to initialize it with the correct `DatabaseReference` and watch the magic happen

Comment: Thank you Chisko! So, Maybe it's better call them listeners? Ok, I'm using a RecyclerView on ChatList activity and I made it's adapter (I didn't add the recyclerview code and it's adapter because I considered I only have the problem on listeners). I have to say I didn't see the FirebaseUI examples on GitHub. Despite this, I have some similarities, but I'm going review them... I have the firebase-ui-database:2.1.1 on my gradle.

Comment: To sum up: I'm creating a chat as whatsapp, so I list chats and chat's messages on RecyclerViews, but I'm stuck quering data to check if the chat was created or not, and why Firebase sometimes retrieve null or data with the same query (and having data available)

Comment: **Possible** reason I can think of is because you are overriding `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` and you don't need to. Another is because you __are__ doing `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` and you need to `addValueEventListener()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155037/discussion-between-jaco-and-chisko).